# How to create unique variable scope names with given prefix?

Tags: tensorflow

I am writing my own functional layers like

```
def vgg_block(x, is_training, output_depth,... name = "vgg_block"):

    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        if pool_size is not None:
            x = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(x, pool_size=pool_size, strides=pool_strides, padding=pool_padding)

        for i_conv in range(n_convs):
            x = conv2d_bn(x, is_training, output_depth, kernel_size=conv_size, strides=conv_strides, padding=conv_padding, bn=conv_bn,
                          activation=conv_activation)

    return x
```

and would like they can name automatically like build-in ones.

Unfortunately, if I write as above, I am receiving duplicate errors, because my inner functions create the same inner scopes.

Is it possible to ask TF to generate new uniue variable scope name on each call?

Answer (score 2):

do `tf.variable_scope(name=None, default_name=name)` which is guaranteed to create a new variable scope with a name like name.